# Extract all Images alt text from web page in Java using jSoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to extract alt text for all images in web page. 
I have tried all the approaches, I know. You can check 
below code.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B003FYLW9Q/ref=olp_f_new?ie=UTF8&f_new=true")
    .userAgent("Mozilla")
    .timeout(50000)
    .cookie("cookiename", "val234")
    .cookie("anothercookie", "ilovejsoup")
    .referrer("http://google.com")
    .header("headersecurity", "xyz123")
    .get();


// Method 1
Elements images = doc.select("img[src~=(?i)\\.(gif)]");
System.out.println(images.attr("alt"));  

// Method 2
String imageAlt = doc.getElementsByClass("a-spacing-none olpSellerName").select("img").attr("alt");
System.out.println(imageAlt);
```

Now this code does not work for the link right now in connect method.
It does not work for some link and it does not fetch all URLs alt in that webpage.

But this works for below links:

https://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B06XWZWYVP/ref=olp_f_new?ie=UTF8&f_new=true

https://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B079JD7F7G/ref=olp_f_new?ie=UTF8&f_new=true

The class is same for all the links. But it does not work for some links. Can any one please tell me the solution for this problem.

Comment: `img[alt]` should work just fine.

Comment: Yes, it works fine. But this code does fetch all images alt text. It does not works for some links.

Comment: You'll need to select links separately with `a[alt]`.

Comment: I want to get alt text from img tags only.

Comment: Do you want to retrieve the `alt` attribute or `href` or `src`?

Comment: only want to retrieve alt.

Comment: The `alt` attribute is used for `img` tags only. Could you point out where it doesn't work?

Comment: One image is present on the links above. But this code only fetch alt for the below two links, it does fetch alt for the link the is present in connect method.

Image has same URL and alt for all links.

Comment: When you run the above code. You will get nothing.

Comment: @MyThemesCafe  Can you try this code? ```String imageAlt = doc.select(".a-spacing-none.olpSellerName").select("img").attr("alt");```

Comment: I have already try it.

Comment: Can you add some examples out of the HTML where your methods do not work?

Comment: I have given the links, you can run that. The link is the connect method is not working for this code. But the 2 links given below are working properly.

Comment: Link contents may change over time. This is not a good SO question if it relies on external resources. One thing I notice in your code is your use of spaces and css classes. If you want to make sure that all elements that you select carry both classes, you need to combine them with a ```.```, but this was already pointed out by @madplay yesterday. Another idea would be to look at the loaded HTML content more closely. Are you sure all images are loaded by the original server call? Nothing loaded via AJAX? Jsoup does not interpret JavaScript, so AJAX calls do not work as you may think.